# Slide animation from right to left using scrollMagic

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm new to GSAP.

I was following MilklsNice's ScrollMagic & GSAP tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDY9M5CquuUdz0y-nsROamHpBayX63ygv).

One of GSAP animation he explained how to make an animation that ***looks like opening a book from LEFT to RIGHT***.

```js
var overlay_test = document.querySelector('.overlay_test');

var animate_in = new TimelineMax();

animate_in
    .fromTo(overlay_test, 2, 
    {skewX: 10, scale: 1.5}, 
    {skewX: 0, xPercent: 100, transformOrigin: "0% 100%", ease: Power2.easeOut})
```

```css
.box_test{
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 350px;
}

.img_test{
    width: 800px;
}

.overlay_test{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="box_test">
   <img class="img_test" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553696801-25638feb93fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="korea">
    <div class="overlay_test"></div>
</div>
```

(You can also check out [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/axbdQR) for this)

At this [webpage](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17547-animate-width-from-left-to-right/), I learned how to show a div from right to left. The code is the following:

```js
var left = new TimelineMax ();

var rect = document.getElementById('rect');

left
  .from(rect,2,{width:0},1)
  .from(rect,2,{left:400},1)
```

```css
Result
EDIT ON
 body{
  background: #414141;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#rect{
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:350px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: green;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#copy{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  
}
h1{
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 145px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.very{
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect">
  <div id="copy">
    <h1 class="very">Very cool </h1>
    <h1>  Jack!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

(You can also check out for [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/qwBbVJ) for this)

BY THE WAY,
this animation is NOT exactly what I wanted. Because, it just moves a div from right to left ***instead of opening it like a book from right to left***. However, I still tried:

```js
var overlay_test = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay_test');

var animate_in = new TimelineMax();

animate_in
  .from(overlay_test,2,{width:0},1)
  .from(overlay_test,2,{left:800},1)
```

```css
.box_test{
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 350px;
}

.img_test{
    width: 800px;
}

.overlay_test{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="box_test">
   <img class="img_test" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553696801-25638feb93fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="korea">
    <div class="overlay_test"></div>
</div>
```

(You can also check out for [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/wZvMNz) for this)

Now, the image disappears. So, I thought that I could apply the animation to the picture instead of the overlay image. However, now the animation starts from top-left corner of the screen as a very tiny image and expand from there.

```js
var img_test = document.querySelectorAll('.img_test');

var animate_in = new TimelineMax();

animate_in
  .from(img_test,2,{width:0},1)
  .from(img_test,2,{left:800},1)
```

```css
.box_test{
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 350px;
}

.img_test{
    width: 800px;
}

.overlay_test{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="box_test">
   <img class="img_test" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553696801-25638feb93fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="korea">
</div>
```

(You can also check out [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/LvYNLE) for this)

This is not what I want either.

> I want to make an animation that ***looks like opening a book from
>   RIGHT to LEFT***. (the opposite of [what I include at the
>   beginning](https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/axbdQR).)

How could I make it happen? :)

Comment: what do you mean `open book` like this:https://codepen.io/wwwebneko/pen/XjOZZK ??

Comment: @לבני מלכה So.. I want to do the opposite. In https://codepen.io/wwwebneko/pen/XjOZZK, the book is being opened from left to right. But, I want to do it from right to left. In https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/axbdQR, the pic is shown from left to right. But, I want to show the pic from right to left. I'm not sure if I made what I wanted to do more clear...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in animation `right:0` to `right:200%` also in css change `left:0` to `right:0`

[See code](https://codepen.io/leenmalka/pen/MRWJVw)

```js
var overlay_test = document.querySelector('.overlay_test');

var animate_in = new TimelineMax();

animate_in
    .fromTo(overlay_test, 2, 
    {skewX: 10, scale: 1.5 , right:0 }, 
    {skewX: 0, right:"200%" ,transformOrigin: "0% 100%", ease: Power2.easeOut})
```

```css
.box_test{
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 350px;
}

.img_test{
    width: 800px;
}

.overlay_test{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="box_test">
   <img class="img_test" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553696801-25638feb93fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="korea">
    <div class="overlay_test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 난 한국을 사랑해 :)   :)

Comment: That's great to hear! 감사합니다! XD